# Получение адреса до БД и определнной таблицы

Tags: java, mysql

Есть подключение к удаленной БД, в которой множество таблиц. Указываю адрес до БД вот таким вот образом в своем конфиге:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://92.222.71.96:3306/forumdb?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Выбираю таблицу и значения..

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `money` FROM `st_users` WHERE `username`=?");
```

Или же обновляю значения

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE `st_users` SET `money`=`money`-? WHERE `username`=?");
```

Но значения не добавляются, не записываются новые.
Полные права для удаленных подключений юзеру даны. В чем может быть проблема?
Структура примерно следующая:
 - forumdb (бд)
   - st_users (необходимая таблица)

Код класса, который работает с БД: http://pastebin.com/HfReLEnb

При подключении получаю вывод в консоль "Totally failed to select player balance! Giving up".

Comment: conn.commit() или флаг setAutoCommit установлен?

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите минимальный воспроизводимый пример (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и включите его в вопрос.

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov прошу прощения, я не силен в работе с БД, подскажите, где проверить этот флаг? Работаю с MySQL под управлением Debian8.

Comment: у объекта `Connection`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)

Comment: conn.commit() установлен, выполняется. Суть в том, что на локальном ПК все работало успешно. На разных удаленных машинах же, нет. (сервер с обработчиком <-> удаленная БД). Думаю поднять локальную бд под сервером с обработчиком и проверить все еще разок.